# Gear Shift lever very stiff going into 1st gear - Fiat Doblo 1.3 Diesel (75hp)

Tags: shifting, clutch-cable

Had to change the clutch due to a problem with pressure plate /throwout bearing (were completely broken - photos attached). Symptoms were very noisy clutch and stiff pedal due to severely damaged pressure plate springs.

[image]

1 week later, after reassemble, was unable to go into first gear and second gears. After adjustment of the gear cables, 2nd gear goes relatively smooth but really struggle to go into 1st.

Next,  will try to lubrificate the gear cables (which had the grease boot ruined). 
Other options that I'm considering is damaged gear cables (seemed to be twisted, don't know if it is normal) , bent gear shift stick, or the gear shift lever at the transmission.

Was unable to change into first/second gears at the transmission, but will try to assess that again.

Any other ideas/ common problems with this transmission?

(the problem happens either with engine off or running)

Thanks in advance

[image]